# UIWebView VS WKWebView to load local html

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, webkit, wkwebview

i create a html string with 500 p tag with timestamp in it

i use `UIWebView` and `WKWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL:` to load it,and `wkWebView` is slower about **50%** than `UIWebVIew`. why?

```
UIWebView:0.1681529879570007
WKWebView:0.3913570046424866
```

Answer (score 1):

WKWebView is faster for displaying html from Strings. However, there is a bug that makes UIWebView faster by default, which is the phone number detection.

Running a viewController with the following code, `webView` being respectively a UIWebView and WKWebView instance and keeping everything else identical I found WKWebView to take up to 2 seconds to load, while UIWebView loads almost instantly.

```
webView.loadHTMLString(HtmlStringInstance, baseURL: nil)
```

I'm by far not the only one to find this:

- [when I use wkwebview to load local html,I find it renders slower than uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169989/when-i-use-wkwebview-to-load-local-html-i-find-it-renders-slower-than-uiwebview)
- [UIWebView delay in loading local content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852257/uiwebview-delay-in-loading-local-content)
- [Slow loading UIWebView from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273289/slow-loading-uiwebview-from-string)
- [Delay in loading a HTML string into a UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292616/delay-in-loading-a-html-string-into-a-uiwebview)
- [Why UIWebView work so slowly when loadHTMLString with UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564908/why-uiwebview-work-so-slowly-when-loadhtmlstring-with-uiwebview)

However, the solution is easy: Disable phone number detection for WKWebView and poof. There you go.

Comment: For me, turning off phone number detection didn't help

Answer (score 1):

For me, creating static variable to avoid creating WKWebView multiple times worked. Objective-C example:

```
- (WKWebView *)webHeaderView
{
    static WKWebView *_webHeaderView = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (!_webHeaderView)
        {
            WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
            _webHeaderView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
        }
    });

    return _webHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: FYI, when I was working with this on real device, I didn't notice huge difference of loading time with WKWebView. I only noticed it when it was for simulator. 

However, if you have multiple views to load WKWebView, above solution might help you since it does take some time to load up WKWebView initially. Be aware that you might run into weird run time issue if this static variable is not released well, so you have to take that into consideration. For me, I moved away from this method because of run time crashes, and I couldn't find good way to remedy that.

Answer (score 0):

`WKWebView` rendering performance is noticeable in WebGL games and something that runs complex JavaScript algorithms which `UIWebView` lacks.

You check the performance both in the [Github](https://github.com/MallowTech/iOS_tips/blob/master/ios_tips/2016-04-28-UIWebView-vs-WKWebView-Performance.md).

Comment: i think WKWebView use JIT for javascript, so its performance is noticeable, but my html do not include js or css, WKWebView is slow, isn't it ?

Comment: im having the same after updating my code to use WKWebView. it loads slower next to UIWebView :/

Answer (score -1):

To make `WKWebView` faster, disabling WKWebView's data detectors worked for me. Swift version:

```
let webViewCofig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewCofig.dataDetectorTypes = []
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webViewCofig)
```

To enable specific data detector, pass the specific type as .address,.link etc while setting dataDetectorTypes:

```
config.dataDetectorTypes = [.address]
```

Comment: `dataDetectorTypes` defaults to `.none`, so this is unnecessary.