# Significant drop in performance after migrating from UIWebView to WKWebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The project I'm working on was using Xamarin Forms (3.4.0.x) Cross Platform, so obviously the iOS app had the UIWebView built in.

We decided to migrate to WKWebView, which required the Xamarin Forms 4.4 update so we proceeded to do that then added `[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.WkWebViewRenderer))]` to the AssemblyInfo.cs in our iOS app, like it says to do here. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/3346

Now I think that's all I need to do completely migrate to WK, but I have noticed that the app has slowed down significantly, taking ~5x as long to load a page, and on top of that, this loading icon stays on the screen even after the page is done loading

My questions are:
Did I migrate correctly, or are there any steps I'm missing/did wrong? Has anyone run into this loading icon problem before? Please ask me to clarify if I'm leaving information out, I'm new to Xamarin Forms so I'm not sure how to ask the best questions, and this is a big project I'm being introduced to. I have been told there is no custom iOS WebView Renderer though, so everything is done using the default WebView.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is [a native iOS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53527592/11104068) caused because of the time it takes to detect phone numbers on the web page. So if you just disable that detection, it should work better.

Here's a sample of how you can do it in Xamarin:

```
var urlRequest = new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https://www.gooogle.com"));
var config = new WebKit.WKWebViewConfiguration();
config.DataDetectorTypes = WebKit.WKDataDetectorTypes.Address;
var frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect();
var webView = new WebKit.WKWebView(frame, config);
webView.LoadRequest(urlRequest);
```

If you followed the link you shared, you should be able to put the code inside the SetElement function of the WkWebViewRenderer. So your code would look like this:

```
var config = new WebKit.WKWebViewConfiguration();
config.DataDetectorTypes = WebKit.WKDataDetectorTypes.Address;
WebView = new WebKit.WKWebView(WebView.Frame, config);
```

Comment: Hi! What do you mean time it takes to detect phone numbers on the webpage? Do you mean like the numbers of the accounts that login to the app? 

Also, where would I put that code?? In AssembyInfo.cs of the iOS app? Thanks!

Comment: @chung So the browser may contain phone numbers that can be hyperlinked automatically by iOS, so that takes a lot of time. I updated the code to work with your scenario

Comment: Oh ok, and sorry but again what file would I put that code in? I searched SetElement in my whole project but there was no function that looked like that. Do I put it in AssemblyInfo.cs? Or do I have to create a new file?

Comment: @chung I think @Saamer is suggesting that you subclass `WkWebViewRenderer`. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/WkWebViewRenderer.cs#L48 You'll also need to change the name of the renderer you specified in `AssemblyInfo.cs` to the name of your subclass. If you're unfamiliar with subclassing, you'll need to do some more research on it.

Comment: Hmm so if I don't have a WkWebViewRenderer.cs I would have to create one in my project? @mattsven

Comment: @chung Take a look at this article on subclassing. It should give you some guidance: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-method-overriding/ Here's why that article is applicable: you're subclassing `WKWebViewRenderer`, in order to override its `SetElement` method with your own.

Comment: Hey, it's been a while, coming back to this bug. So I placed that code block into my SetElement function, but I'm getting an error saying WKWebViewRenderer.WebView cannot be assigned to, it is read only.

Comment: Yeah, I just created a Renderer file and copied everything over from https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/WkWebViewRenderer.cs and then inside the SetElement function, I added those 3 lines

Comment: The errors are, in more detail `Property or indexer WkWebViewRenderer.WebView cannot be assigned to -- it is read only` and `WebView does not contain a definition for Frame and no extension method Frame is accepting a first argument of type WebView`, both from the last line.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to tag you @Saamer

Comment: @chung He wrote `WebView.Frame` there means you should create your own frame of your webView. Like    `CoreGraphics.CGRect webViewFrame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0,0,100,100);`.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier solution that just went public from the [Xamarin team](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/). All you need to do is update the Forms Nuget, Visual Studio, and Xamarin.iOS, and then:

> ... go to your iOS project, open the project properties and add this flag in the additional mtouch arguments field: --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type.